# One View for multiple models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

If you need to create one View from various entity (models), is it best to create a separate class as a ViewModel containing the specific properties that you need or is it better to create another entity with the specific properties and associate that entity with the rest of the entities in the ORM designer?

Comment: i always found a 1:1 view-to-model ratio works best (then you can use something like AutoMapper to make the linking easier).

Comment: This is probably down to personal preference, I would add the 2 entity models to a view model. I wouldn't make extra entities as it would just clutter the db design

Comment: I would use a view model.

Comment: I agree with the ViewModel approach. thx...

Comment: However, this is the one "bad" thing I find with MVC as opposed to WebForms --- the requirement where a View can only use ONE View. I mean really, how many times are you going to be selecting a result set from strictly one entity or even and "Include" with eager loading for another child entity? It's almost always going to be a combination of data from several entities, thereby making your whole MVC project a mass of manually created ViewModels. If someone can give me a good and efficient reason why the MVC approach would be better, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge any number of models into one model by declaring them a property of the main m odel. Suppose that you have the following models:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }

    public virtual School StudentSchool { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public School()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();            
    }

    public int SchoolID { get; set; }
    public string ASchoolName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }        
}
```

If you just set the `Student` class as your view model, you can retrive the `School` of your student and in this case you doesn't need to do anything.

However we suppose that you also need **all** schools and  **all** students in your view as your view model. To do this, create another class and add the above classes as its properties:

```
public class MyModel
{
    List<Student> MyStudents { get; set; }
    List<School> MySchools { get; set; }
}
```

You can create any complex model you need by this approach...